How to increment a value when initializing a struct?
Initializing a struct with an unsigned short id using a #define ...

static unsigned short mId = 0;

typedef struct
{
    /* data */
    unsigned short id;
    const char *name;
    bool enabled;
} Machine;

#define CREATE_MACHINE(_mName_) Machine m##_mName_ = {mId++, #_mName_, false};


How can I increment mId for the next instance initialization? mId++ is not allowed in the initializer.
So, I've also tried with a function as one comment suggested:
static Machine _create_machine(const char *name)
{
    unsigned short id = mId++;
    Machine m = {id, name, false};

    return m;
}

// corrected typo in method parameter
#define CREATE_MACHINE(_mName_) Machine m##_mName_ = _create_machine(#_mName_);

Can't use a function in a constant expression.
Full source per request...
// main.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#include "../include/machine.h"

MAKE_MACHINE(test)

int main()
{
    PLACE(mtest);
    printf("placed machine[%d] enabled: %s\n", mtest.id, B(mtest.enabled);

    DROP(mtest);
    printf("dropped machine[%d] enabled: %s\n", mtest.id, B(mtest.enabled);
}

// machine.h
#ifndef MACHINE_H
#define MACHINE_H

#include "op/data_types.h"

static USHORT mId = 0;

enum MachineState
{
    M_IDLE,
    M_RUN,
    M_LOCK
};

typedef struct
{
    /* data */
    const USHORT id;
    const CHAR *name;
    BOOL enabled;
} Machine;

static Machine _make_machine(const char *name)
{
    USHORT id = mId++;
    Machine m = {id, name, false};

    return m;
}

static void _place_machine(Machine *machine)
{
    machine->enabled = true;
}
static void _drop_machine(Machine *machine)
{
    machine->enabled = false;
}

#define MAKE_MACHINE(_mName_) Machine m##_mName_ = _make_machine(#_mName_);

#define PLACE(_machine_) _place_machine(&_machine_);
#define DROP(_machine_) _drop_machine(&_machine_);

#endif //  MACHINE_H


Use a function?  You'd want one anyway if you're going to create a Machine in multiple threads at one time.

I tried using a function and it didn't like using a function either because it is a constant value ...??? That's what the IDE complained about. I'll add that as something I've tried.

Why try to do this with a macro, with a dynamically defined variable name containing sequential numbers? Why not just store them in an array?

Are you trying to use this macro to create file scope instances?  That would explain why mId++ gives you a problem.

@user229044 Because the struct has an id which needs to be incrementally assigned.

@dbush: yes ... that's the intent. I'm following some techniques I've recently come across and learning the limitations, benefits, pros & cons. But at least I now have a clue as to why it isn't working. I'd like to find a solution, though (if there is one).

How are you compiling your function version?  That compiles clean for me (gcc m.c -Wall -Wextra -o m).

A function will work.  Full working example:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

static unsigned short mId = 0;

typedef struct
{
    /* data */
    unsigned short id;
    const char *name;
    bool enabled;
} Machine;

static Machine make_machine(const char * name) {
    // lock mutexes, atomic operations, etc.
    unsigned short next_id = mId++;
    // unlock mutexes if necessary
    Machine ret = {next_id, name, false};
    return ret;
}

#define CREATE_MACHINE(_mName_) Machine m##_mName_ = make_machine(#_mName_)

int main() {
    CREATE_MACHINE(hello);
    CREATE_MACHINE(world);
    printf("%u: %s\n", mhello.id, mhello.name);
    printf("%u: %s\n", mworld.id, mworld.name);
    return 0;
}

Because the function isn't constrained in the same way, we can do extra work there like increment mId.  If you want to use different incrementing ID variables, make_machine could take a unsigned short* that it manipulates within the function itself, and that could still be hidden by the macro.

Okay, so this is how to properly initialize a file scoped value. If I did want to make these constants, how would I go about doing that? I misunderstood what was referred to in the post comments regarding file scope.

You want the created Machine to be const?  You'd just add const to the type in the macro (const Machine m##_mName_ = ...).

well, I guess I meant globally scoped  as opposed to file. The IDE was complaining that a function could not be used in a constant expression, so I guess it's not a const. Still grasping the concepts. I'm getting it though. Appreciate the helps.

If you [edit] your question to show your initial attempt in full and what's not working, I'll play with it and see what I can do.  It's fine if it doesn't compile, but it's easier than guessing what your code looks like.

@StephenNewell Using either macro at file scope doesn't work, as the initializer contains an expression which is not a constant expression.

I am going a slightly different approach. This answer is most helpful in realizing where the limitation is in my approach.

Using macros like these to hide variable declarations is usually not the best idea, as you are creating some "macro language" which is hard to read and maintain.
That being said, it's quite possible to do all of this at compile-time. I'd roll out the "X-macros" design pattern and place all names in a list:
#define MACHINE_NAMES(X) \
  X(Bob)                 \
  X(Bill)                \

We can then generate an enum based on this:
typedef enum
{
  #define MACHINE_ENUM(name) MACHINE_##name,
  MACHINE_NAMES(MACHINE_ENUM)
} machine_enum_t;

All the variable declarations then become:
#define CREATE_MACHINE(name) Machine m##name = {MACHINE_##name, #name, false};
MACHINE_NAMES(CREATE_MACHINE)

Past preprocessing, you are now sitting on something like:
Machine mBob  = {MACHINE_Bob,  "Bob",  false};
Machine mBill = {MACHINE_Bill, "Bill", false};

Where MACHINE_Bob == 0, MACHINE_Bill == 1 and so on. You probably should make it an array though - where MACHINE_##name gives you the array index.

If I'm understanding this approach correctly, I need to know all the machines in advance. Is that correct?

@IAbstract Yes that's the requirement for anything which resolves at compile-time.
